# Executable made with pyInstaller/UPX experiences DLL load failed: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller, upx

**Executable made with pyInstaller / UPX in virtual environment throws an error**

`DLL load failed: The parameter is incorrect. while parameter is correct...`

I've made python Executable without`pyInstaller UPX` Its about `250MB` & Its working Fine.

To reduce size I've created another python Executable (Contains Same Code) Using **pyInstaller UPX** and its gives me an error refer [Error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIgb7.png).

Code Contains libraries like `Pandas,Numpy,Openpyxl`

**The error is showing at line 8 where I've defined Pandas library**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the solution and It's working perfectly Fine...
Need to add Pandas and Numpy Manually using pyinstaller --add-data option

`pyinstaller --add-data C:\ve\mypython\Lib\site-packages\pandas;pandas --add-data C:\ve\mypython\Lib\site-packages\numpy;numpy --icon=icon_file.ico --version-file version.txt --noconsole --upx-dir=C:\upx --upx-exclude vcruntime140.dll --upx-exclude ucrtbase.dll --onefile Foo.py`

`After creating Executable the size of an EXE is 170MB.`